# How the Openshift Ingress Object picked up by particular router

Tags: openshift, ingress-controller

lets say we have IngressControllerA , IngressControllerB and created Ingress Object IngressA, IngressB, how to tell IngressA object router to be pickedup by IngressControllerA  and IngressB object router to be pickedup by IngressControllerB.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the IngressController will pick up any Ingress in the cluster. What you are trying to do is called "Ingress Sharding" when different IngressControllers are managing different Ingresses.

You can shard the Ingresses by setting labels: [Configuring Ingress Controller sharding by using route labels](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.10/networking/configuring_ingress_cluster_traffic/configuring-ingress-cluster-traffic-ingress-controller.html#nw-ingress-sharding-route-labels_configuring-ingress-cluster-traffic-ingress-controller) or by using namespace labels: [Configuring Ingress Controller sharding by using namespace labels](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.10/networking/configuring_ingress_cluster_traffic/configuring-ingress-cluster-traffic-ingress-controller.html#nw-ingress-sharding-namespace-labels_configuring-ingress-cluster-traffic-ingress-controller)

So you'll need to set the `routeSelector` for your IngressController:

```
    routeSelector:
      matchLabels:
        type: sharded
```

Then you can label the Ingress / Route:

```
oc label route example type=sharded
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked fine. How to verify it that Ingress Object , picked up by a particular router.

Comment: You can either check the generated configuration inside the Router Pod or try to access the Route via the Routers themselves. The Router Pods expose port 80 and 443 on the node they are running on.